# show plotly lables without hovering

Tags: python, plotly

using the following code, I have been trying to get the data lables for a vilon plot to show without having to hover over it:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
data = np.random.randn(30)
fig6 = go.Figure(data=go.Violin(y=data, box_visible=True, line_color='black',
                               meanline_visible=True, fillcolor='lightseagreen', opacity=0.6
                               ))

fig6.update_layout(yaxis_zeroline=False)
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+text")
fig6.show()
```

Sadly this result in an error and I am unable to determin how to solve my problem. Does a solution exists?

Edit, the error is

```
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Box: 'mode'
```

Comment: what is the error? Try to give as much useful information as possible about your issue, not just throwing a piece of code and a question... The scope is to make a post useful, not just for you, but for others that will face the same issue in the future.

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou I have edited the post to include the error.

Comment: When I run your code, no error occurs. My environment is the latest 5.3.1. What version are you using?

Comment: I guess, you want to update the traces for fig6 and not for fig, but it is not the problem. I think Viloin plots do not have a property mode (see your error message). May be you can use a scatter plot “behind” your violin plot and than you can set the mode for the scatter plot to “markers+text”.

Comment: @Bibzon That could work though if that is the case, any ideas on how I can extract the coordinates and lables from the vilon plot to put on to the scatter plot? I would like to avoide, if posible, having to recalulate the IQR for a separate set of data lables.

Comment: @r-beginners I am also using 5.3.1